# How to delete object in an array in a reducer in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, reducers

I know my question is already ask but I don't think in this terms :

I want to delete an item on my reducer but everthing I tried didn't work.

I tried many things but after 2 days blocked on this I think I need help !

Here is the dispatcher :

```
store.dispatch({
     type: 'REMOVE_COIN',
     payload: {
          id:coinId
      }
 })
```

Here is the reducer :

```
const intialState = {
}

const coinReducer = (state = intialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case "REGISTER_COIN":
            return {
                ...state,
                [action.payload.id]: {
                    id:action.payload.id,
                    position:action.payload.position,
                }
            }
        case "REMOVE_COIN":

            const newState = Object.assign([], state)
            // console.log(newState)

            // if (newState.includes(Object(action.payload.id)) > -1) {
                // console.log('OUI')
            // }else{
                // console.log('NON')
            // }

            // const newState = [...state]
            // const index = newState.findIndex(coin => coin.id == action.payload.id)
            // if (index !== -1) {
            //     newState.splice(index, 1);
            //     console.log(newState)
            // }

            const finalState = newState.filter(coin => coin.id !== action.payload.id)
            console.log(finalState)
            // const coinId = action.payload.id

            // // console.log(newState)

            // const indexOfCatToDelete = newState.findIndex(coin => coin.id == String(action.payload.id))


            // console.log(indexOfCatToDelete)
            // newState.splice(indexOfCatToDelete, 1)
            // console.log(newState)
            // return newState     
            // return {
            //     state : newState.filter( (item, index) => index !== action.index)
            //  }    
            // return finalState
            // const numIndex = parseInt(action.index)
            // return {
            //     state: [
            //     ...state.slice(0, numIndex),
            //     ...state.slice(numIndex+ 1)
            //     ]
            // }
        default:
            return state
    }
}

export default coinReducer
```

I let all the comment to show everything I tried.

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have your initial state as an array for this to work. Or add `coins` property to it, which is an array:

```
const initialState = [];
// Or 
const initialState = {coins: []}
```

Make sure that you're actually receiving `action` with `payload.id` and then you can return the filtered state in your reducer:

```
case "REMOVE_COIN":
  // OR state.coins.filter if that's what you have on the state
  return state.filter(coin => String(coin.id) !== String(action.payload.id));
```

**Edit**: Looking back at your reducer, I noticed that you have the state as an object, where coin id is a prop. In that case you'll need to filter the state by object keys:

```
case "REMOVE_COIN":
  return Object.keys(state)
  .filter(key => key !== String(action.payload.id))
  .reduce((obj, key) => {
    obj[key] = state[key];
    return obj;
  }, {});
```